# ASP.NET redirect to another website and log out the user (session.abandon)

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms

i would like to redirect logged-in users who request myDomain/somePage.aspx to anotherDomain/somePage.aspx and when end their session (they will have to log-in if they back to myDomain)
i understood that the redirection happens after the page is completly loads and renderd, and therefore i guess the session termination can invoked in some event on page lifecycle.
does the next solution is good? someone has better idea? (i guess i'm not the first one who face the problem)

```
onLoad()
{
Respone.Redirect(anotherDomain/somePage.aspx,false);
Session.abandon()  //or some other function which call abandon
}
```

someone has better idea? do it with ajax on client side is better?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` ends the current execution (you'll get a `ThreadAbortException`), no code after that will be executed. So your code won't work (you're also missing quotes around your path, but that might be just a copy/paste thing).

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

and then redirect.